# Suddenly unable to connect to my raspberry pi via ssh

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to connect to my raspberry pi via ssh, but I receive `NCURSES6_TINFO_5.0.19991023' not found`

```
bruni@PROX15:~$ ssh pi@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Linux raspberrypi 6.1.21+ #1642 Mon Apr  3 17:19:14 BST 2023 armv6l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Wed Dec 27 19:31:55 2023
-bash: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtinfo.so.6: version `NCURSES6_TINFO_5.0.19991023' not found (required by -bash)
Connection to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx closed.
```

What could be the reason and how could I possibly resolve this?

Comment: What did you do before you get such errors? Did you updated the system? Installed an external package? or what? Then possibly you can execute dash from ssh, but it would be difficult, so you should prepare what you need to do to restore the system (and you must to know the reason the system is broken)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I may have updated the system and there was a power outage (though not at the time of the update). I seldom install new packages on this system, as it is used as a file server for backups and I do not need much more than samba/ssh/tmux.

Comment: Try `ssh pi@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx /bin/dash, then `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` and ev, also `apt reinstall libtinfo5`

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks, unfortunately I get the same error

Comment: So try just `ssh pi@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx sudo apt update` , etc., but I'm not so optimistic: such command will probably open the shell (and possibly the shell will require interactive libraries also when called by a script).

Comment: If you have physical access, get the SD card and fsck it on another system. I had a similar error on a raspberry and it was a filesystem problem, because of card wear, and it had to be replaced.

Comment: *Most likely :* SD card corruption/wearout. If you have a backup (.img file), you're in reasonably good shape. If not, retain your old SD card as there's probably quite a lot of data that has survived & you can get that data by loop mounting the "old" card on your Pi via USB-SD adapter.  IMHO, `fsck` is a waste of time on SD cards... but it's your time.